# Why should I use Iesi.Collections instead of the traditional System.Collection?

Tags: nhibernate, asp.net-mvc-4

Was research on how (for convetion) define a Many Many where table where both fields are primary key and found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6272802/491181).

So decide to install the [Iesi.Collections](http://nuget.org/packages/Iesi.Collections/) in my library domain.

But there came a doubt. In the "Iesi.Collections" outperforms "System.Collections" Iesi.Collections?
Why should I use?

It is better in performance?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Iesi.Collections was originally [released in 2004](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3190/Add-Support-for-quot-Set-quot-Collections-to-NET), when the .NET Framework was at v1.1. As of .NET 3.5, the .NET Framework includes a [HashSet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397727%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) collection type, which provides the Set functionality that Iesi.Collections was intended to address. Unless you have a specific reason to use Iesi.Collections (e.g., NHibernate depends on it), it probably makes sense to use the standard .NET classes instead, since they are more likely to be supported and maintained.